# How to obtain indices of repetitive values based on condition

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, vectorization

I am trying with following code, but get indice of last value only

```
A=[ 3 4 1 2 4 4 4]
B=unique(A)
[b1  b2]=max(B)

while i<=numel(A)
 if A(i)==A(b2)
    ID=A(i)
end
end
```

Is there any way other in matlab to get all indices of value 4 (max value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the indices of the largest value in your matrix, there is no need for `unique` at all.  It's superfluous.  Just use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and `max` simultaneously:

```
ID = find(A == max(A));
```

`max(A)` returns the largest value in `A`.  `A == max(A)` returns a `logical` vector where `1` corresponds to a value in `A` matching the largest value in `A` and `0` otherwise.  Finally, `find` determines the locations in the input that are non-zero, so in effect we are finding the locations that match the largest value in `A`.